# Is it possible to pre populate a password (stored as hashed form in the db)?

Tags: security, cookies, hash, spring-security

I think this is a bad practice, but ignore that for now.

If I have a login form (username/password and a remember me checkbox). Is it possible to pre populate the username and pwd fields if a user is remembered ?

Comment: Pre-populate password field with **dots**?

Comment: With the actual password (masked) I am afraid.

Comment: Is this for a web site or a desktop application?

Comment: If the user is remembered, then you just log them in without displaying the login form at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you are hashing them correctly. If you could, then that would be a weakness that attackers could exploit.

In short, don't do that.